# Django PhoneNumberField library giving problem when using bootstrap class

Tags: django

I am using PhoneNumberField library. But when I access the field and give bootstrap class, the layout changes. It displays PhoneNumberPrefixWidget in one line and PhoneNumberField in another line. I want them to display next to each other. I tried using for loop but I still couldn't get what I want.

forms.py

```
phone_no = PhoneNumberField(
        widget=PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
```

In settings.py

```
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = 'NATIONAL'
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = 'BT'
```

In my html template

```
{{ form.phone_no }}
```

Is there a way to access this fields separately? By default when I access {{form.phone_no}}, both the fields appear together

Thanks in advance

Comment: comment here to follow this question. I have the same problem. In fact, I also have problem getting validation error when I use `PhoneNumberPrefixWidget`. Details here https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/issues/443

Answer (score 2):

You can access the elements individually from the template by extending the `MultiWidget` class of concern, and add the following function:

```
class CustomPhoneNumberPrefixWidget(PhoneNumberPrefixWidget):
    def subwidgets(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        return context['widget']['subwidgets']
```

Now instead of using `PhoneNumberPrefixWidget`, you should use `CustomPhoneNumberPrefixWidget` as per snippet below:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        contact_widgets = self.fields['primary_contact'].widget.widgets
        contact_widgets[0].attrs.update({'class': 'col-4 form-select'})
        contact_widgets[1].attrs.update({'class': 'col-8 form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = BookerProfile
        fields = (
            'primary_contact',
            'address',
            'town',
            'postcode',
        )
        widgets = {
            "primary_contact" : CustomPhoneNumberPrefixWidget(),
            "address" : widgets.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "town" : widgets.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "post" : widgets.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

You can then access both elements individually in your template like so (or in a loop):

```
{{ object.primary_contact.subwidgets.0 }}
{{ object.primary_contact.subwidgets.1 }}
```